# Add Image to Facebook Wall

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, uiimage

I am trying to implement a previous answer.  Here is the code recommended:

```
-(void) postImageToFB:(UIImage *) image
{

    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);
    Facebook* fb = [(uploadPicAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] facebook   ];

    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[fb accessToken],@"access_token",
                                @"message text", @"message",
                                imageData, @"source",
                                nil];
    [fb requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" 
               andParams:params 
           andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
             andDelegate:self];


}
```

But I am getting a error not found on the term: uploadPicAppDelegate

I can't find this in the Facebook sdk or a search of the web (other than additional similar code).  Is this a custom created data type --or -- am I missing a file that needs to be imported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your params dictionary the value for `@"source"` should be a link for the picture and not a NSData object.